# How to get each parent page, and display its children as separate divs in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now I have the following PHP:

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages( array( 'sort_column'=>'menu_order', 'parent'=>'0') );
    foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
      $title = $page_data->post_title;
      $slug = $page_data->post_name;
      $pageid=$page_data->ID;

        echo '<div class="section'.(($title=='intro')?' intro-section':"").'">';
        echo $content;
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

There are 5 Pages, 2 of which have many child Pages. I want to take the above code further one level, so that each page will have its own wrapper, and, if a Page has children Pages, those pages will be placed within the same `.section`, but each within a separate `div`. Any advice? I'm a bit inexperienced in Wordpress so any help would be great. Below should give an example of what I want:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="page parent"></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="page parent"></div>
    <div class="page child"></div>
    <div class="page child"></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="page parent"></div>
</div>
```

Below is the code I'm working with right now.

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
$pages = get_pages( array( 'sort_column'=>'menu_order', 'parent'=>'0') );
    foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
      $title = $page_data->post_title;
      $slug = $page_data->post_name;
      $pageid=$page_data->ID;

        //Put a container around every page's content
      if (count(get_pages('child_of=' . $page_data->ID.''))) {
            // Loop through $page_data array to print the div you want 
        echo '<div class="section">';
        echo '<div class="slide">';
        echo $content;
        echo "</div>";

       $children = get_pages('child_of=' . $page_data->ID.'');
      foreach( $children as $child ) {
        $childcontent = apply_filters('the_content', $child->post_content);
        echo '<div class="slide">';
        echo $childcontent;
        echo "</div>";
      }
      echo "</div><!--end section-->";
      } else {

        echo '<div class="section'.(($title=='intro')?' intro-section':"").'">';
        echo $content;
        echo "</div>";
    }
  }
?>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `child_of` parameter of `get_pages()` function inside the loop. This parameter lists the sub-pages of a single Page only. It uses the `ID` for a Page as the value.

Eg.

```
if (count(get_pages('child_of=' . $page_data->ID))) {
    // Loop through $page_data array to print the div you want 
}
```

Comment: I tried to add that, but I'm getting an `unexpected '{'` error.

Update the post above to reflect what I have.

Comment: I missed a closing parenthesis. Updated the code. Please try now

Comment: Ah yeah I just figured it out!

Okay, so it is detecting that it has child pages, but they aren't printing (ie the Parent page is wrapped with `div.slide`, but there are no other child pages). Do I do a new `while` inside the `if`, to get each child page? I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Yes you will have to loop through $page_data array

Comment: I added a bit of code above that I would expect would output the child's content, but it's not quite working.

Comment: I see. Do you know why what I did above is just returning empty?

Comment: Did you check print_r($children) ?

Comment: It output a large array `WP_Post Object` of the child.

Comment: I figured it out. The post content itself was empty, but there are custom fields (from Advanced Custom Fields.) Now getting it to post those should be interesting. Thanks for your help!